# How do I do a JPQL query with an underscore in the column name?

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, where-clause, jpql

I am getting an error with the following JPQL query:

```
@NamedQuery (name = "Customer.getById", query = 
"SELECT o 
FROM bub.Customer o 
WHERE o.user_id = :myid")
```

[bub.Customer is the @Entity name]

This is an excerpt of the error message I'm receiving:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
Errors in named queries: 
Customer.getById\n 
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
Errors in named queries: Customer.getById
```

When I remove the WHERE clause Wildfly allows me to deploy my web app so I know there is something wrong wtih my WHERE clause.  Specifically since the column name is user_id in my Customer table I believe there may be an issue with the underscore(_) in the JPQL.  I've tried changing the WHERE clause to  "WHERE o.userId = :myid" but that didn't work either.

How can I fix the WHERE clause so my website will deploy and still work the correct way?

EDIT:
The relevant method is this:

```
public static Customer getById (final EntityManager em, final long id)
{
    return em.createNamedQuery ("Customer.getById", Customer.class).setParameter ("myid", id).getSingleResult ();
}
```

I don't think this is the issue though.

EDIT2:
It turns out this was the issue:

```
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn (name = "user_id")
private User         user;
```

I ended up changing the JPQL query to this and now it's working:

```
@NamedQuery (name = "Customer.getById", query = 
"SELECT o 
FROM bub.Customer o 
WHERE o.user = :myid")
```

Comment: post the java code of the entity, too

Comment: I added the method that is calling the query but I don't think that's the issue.  My code won't deploy right now unless I remove the WHERE clause so I believe the WHERE clause is the main issue.

Comment: I meant the Customer class.In JPQL you don't use the column name, but the attribute name(unless you annotate something else)

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much Turo.  If you could post the "In JPQL you don't use the column name, but the attribute name(unless you annotate something else)" as an answer I will select your answer as the correct answer.  Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JPQL you don't use the column name, but the attribute name(unless you annotate something else)